# SQL: Difference between rows

Tags: sql

I am trying to find the difference between two numbers corresponding to the same ID, but with two different conditions. For example,

```
Column A Column B Column C
1234     3         True 
1234     5         False
5678     10        True
5678     15        False
```

So basically  i want to find the difference in Column B when column A is the same but Column C is different.

Comment: will there always be *atmost* 2 rows for each distinct value in columnA?

Comment: Please add tags for database and version if relevant.

Answer (score 0):

If we can assume

- 2 rows for a given value in ColumnA
- expected result is only 1 row returned per unique colA value
- columnC will never be null...
- Column B will never match, and if they do, you don't want the record returned.

We can use a self join checking for matches on column A, no matches on column C and so that we don't get a row each for 1234 of 2 and -2.

```
SELECT Z.ColumnA, Z.B-Y.B
FROM TableName Z
INNER JOIN tableName Y
 on Z.ColumnA = Y.ColumnA
and Z.ColumnC <> Y.ColumnC
and Z.ColumnB > Y.ColumnB
```

you could also do this with a window function using lead and look ahead to the next record. but I don't know if your RDBMS supports window functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
 select t1.ColumnA, t1.ColumnB-t2.ColumnB diff from
 tab t1, tab t2
 where t1.columnA = t2.columnA and t1.ColumnC='True' and t2.ColumnC='False'
```

Answer (score 0):

If your table name is `myTable`, I believe you can join the table with itself and on `Column A` and then select a difference in `Column B` when `Column C` is not equal to itself. So something like this

```
SELECT X.ColumnB - Y.ColumnB as Diff
FROM myTable as X
inner join
     myTable as Y
on X.ColumnA=Y.ColumnA
WHERE X.ColumnC <> Y.ColumnC
```

Answer (score 0):

You could  use a self  join

```
  select a.column_A, a,column_B, b.column_B, a.column_B . b.column_B
  from my_table a 
  inner join my_column b where a.column_a = b.column_a and a.column_c <> b_column_c
```

Answer (score 0):

If you RDBMS supports window functions

```
;with cte as (
    Select *
          ,Change    = ColumnB-Lag(ColumnB,1) over (Partition By ColumnA Order By (Select null))
          ,TrueFalse = Lag(ColumnC,1) over (Partition By ColumnA Order By (Select null))
    From @YourTable
)
Select ColumnA
      ,Change
 From  cte
 Where Change<>0
   and TrueFalse<>ColumnC
```

Returns

```
ColumnA Change
1234    2
5678    5
```

Answer (score 0):

This one subtracts the "true" rows from the "false" rows, while preserving all true rows.

```
SELECT true.columna, true.columnb, COALESCE(false.columnb, 0) - true.columnb AS difference
FROM
(SELECT *
 FROM t
 WHERE columnc = "true") true
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT *
 FROM t
 WHERE columnc = "false) false
ON true.columna = false.columna
```

The coalesce clause will account for cases in which there is no false row. Without it you will end up trying to subtract from NULL.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Oracle, take a look at [User Defined aggregate functions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28425/aggr_functions.htm). If you define a function called `diff()`, then you can use `select column_A, diff(column_B) from my_table group by column_A`, but remember that the implementation of diff needs special care as different ordering will generate different results.